# SSIS Package Not Populating Any Results

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2008, ssis

I'm trying to load data from my database into an excel file of a standard template. The package is ready and it's running, throwing a couple of validation warnings stating that truncation may occur because my template has fields of a slightly smaller size than the DB columns i've matched them to.

However, no data is getting populated to my excel sheet.
No errors are reported, and when I click preview for my OLE DB source, it's showing me rows of results. None of these are getting populated into my excel sheet though.

Comment: as it debugs, the Excel Destination task goes red, while everything else seems fine. 0 Errors, 2 Truncation warnings

Comment: my data flaw has a db source, data conversion and excel destination... the first two run fine... it's the final excel destination that's throwing 2 warnings, but still not populating any data

Comment: [Excel Destination [22]] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80040E21.
[Excel Destination [22]] Error: Cannot create an OLE DB accessor. Verify that the column metadata is valid.
[SSIS.Pipeline] Error: component "Excel Destination" (22) failed the pre-execute phase and returned error code 0xC0202025.

Comment: If it turns red it isn't throwing a warning it is throwing an error. Does your Ecel file exist?

Comment: If you can convince teh people who comnsume this data to let you create a.csv file (which can easily be opened in Excel) you wil have far fewer problems. Far far fewer problems.. SSIS support for Excel is nothing less than atrocious.

Comment: About 90% of teh time when I push back and tell teh customer that it will cost twice as much to develop an Excel import as a csv import, they find excel isn't so necessary after all. Of course you do have to have clients who are paying for the development for that tactic to work.

Answer (score 5):

You should first make sure that you have data coming through the pipeline.  In the arrow connecting your Source task to Destination task (I'm assuming you don't have any steps between), double click and you'll open the Data Flow Path Editor.  Click on Data Viewer, then Add and click OK.  That will allow you to see what is moving through the pipeline.

[image]

Something to consider with Excel is that is prefers Unicode data types to Non-Unicode.  Chances are you have a database collation that is Non-Unicode, so you might have to convert the values in a Data Conversion task.

[image]

[image]

ALSO, you may need to force the package to execute in 32bit runtime.  The VS application develops in a 32bit environment, so the drivers you have visibility to are 32bit.  If there is no 64bit equivalent, it will break when you try and run the package.  Right click on your project and click Properties and under the Debug menu you'll need to change the setting Run64BitRuntime to FALSE.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Couple of questions that may lead to an answer:

1. Have you checked that data is actually passed through the SSIS package at run time?
2. Have you double checked your mapping?
3. Try converting within the package so you don't have the truncation issue

If you add some more details about what you're running, I may be able do give a better answer.

EDIT: Considering what you wrote in your comment, I'd defiantly try the third option. Let us know if this doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: i've already added a data conversion step between my source and destination. It converts my db string columns to unicode strings so i don't get any conversion issues when writing to my destination excel

Answer (score 0):

you dont provide much informatiom. Add a Data View between your source and your excel destination to see if data is passing through.  Do do it, just double click the data flow path, select data view and then add a grid.

Run your app. If you see data, provide more details so we can help you

Answer (score 0):

Just as an assist for anyone else running into this - I had a similar issue and beat my head against the wall for a long time before I found out what was going on.  My export WAS writing data to the file, but because I was using a template file as the destination, and that template file had previous data that had been deleted, the process was appending the data BELOW the previously used rows.  So, I was writing out three lines of data, for example, but the data did not start until row 344!!!

The solution was to select the entire spreadsheet in my template file, and delete every bit of it so that I had a completely clean sheet to begin with.  I then added my header lines to the clean sheet and saved it.  Then I ran the data flow task and...ta-daa!!!  Perfect export!

Hopefully this will help some poor soul who runs into this same issue in the future!